# How to convert timestamp format while using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am using-
 echo $post->entry_time;

this will echo a proper timestamp like - 2015-12-09 13:47:46.
i want to format it with 16 December 2015 with time.

Answer (score 0):

In below i have created function for get UTCmills to Date , just add function in **helper.php** and you can use in view, controller and model,

```
/*
  @return convert UTC milisec to date format
  @param  $milisec , $formate
  @explain 1 $milisec convert to date
  @explain 2 $formate convert as per date format
 */

function UTCmillsToDate($milisec, $formate = "Y-M-D") {
    $mil = $milisec;
    $seconds = $mil / 1000;
    if ($formate == "YMD") {
        return date("Ymd", $seconds);
    } else if ($formate == "Y-M-D") {
        return date("Y-m-d", $seconds);
    } else if ($formate == "d/m/Y") {
        return date("d/m/Y", $seconds);
    } else if ($formate == "Y-m-d H:i:s") {
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
    }else if ($formate == "d-m-Y H:i:s") {
        return date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $seconds);
    }
    else if ($formate == "s") {
        return date("r", $seconds);
    } else {
        return date("d-m-Y", $seconds);
    }
}
```

## Example :

1 ==> UTCmillsToDate('1449750420')
**Output:** 2015-10-12

2 =>  UTCmillsToDate('1449750420','Y-m-d H:i:s')
**Output:** 2015-10-12 12:27:00